# Why does R# warn me about a commented-out line in CSHTML?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, razor, resharper

R# tells me "Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'" on a line that is commented out:

```
// report_params = { GUID: @Model.GUID, SerialNumber: @Model.SerialNumber, ReportName: @Model.ReportName };
```

The light bulb "agent" has options to "Check if Model is not null" and "Assert Model is not null"

Why does Resharper examine commented-out code? Yet, the following live code, gets by unscathed:

```
report_params =
{
    GUID: "@Model.GUID",
    SerialNumber: "@Model.SerialNumber",
    ReportName: "@Model.ReportName"
};
```

Although the quotes around those vals look wrong to me.

### UPDATE

R# is also telling me, "Unknown css class 'staticLabel'" for this line of HTML:

```
<label for="BeginDate" class="staticLabel">Begin Date</label>
```

...when I have, in the very same .cshtml file, in the  section:

```
.staticLabel {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 140px;
    margin-right: 2px;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Consolas, Candara, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: brown;
}
```

(it's not complaining about other classes there supposedly being unknown)

### UPDATE 2

I had an "unmatched closing tag" ( was duplicated, with the rogue rapscallion hidden way out at line 486).

Comment: Are you sure? This is a bug, report it in their bug tracking site.

Comment: Seems like you are commenting out the JavaScript, server side code inside JavaScript comment will still execute and that's what R# is complaining.

Comment: I've added CSHTML to title - feel free to rollback. Note: make sure to test for  "script injection" in your code (or at least potential for invalid output) - if ReportName contains interesting characters (like quotes).

Comment: @Alexei; that's fine - thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an ASP.NET MVC razor view the comment tags are @* code *@.  The // does not comment out the line in razor.

Comment: Okay, then Visual Studio is messing up, because when I select the line and mash Ctrl+K, C (comment), it prepends the whack-whack.

Comment: @ClayShannon I think that's because Visual Studio isn't able to differentiate between C#/Code-behind and ASP.NET's Razor code when using shortcuts like that. dwilson is correct, though. You have to comment it out using @*  code *@  otherwise it's still being executed, and will simply display "//" on your webpage.

Comment: Interesting.  That shortcut key combination is working for me in VS2012.  Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: @dwilson: 2010 and 2003 here at work (2012 at home). This project: 2010 Professional.